# jquery hide table column, nth-child slow performance?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a fairly large html table and I'm adding a new rows dynamically using jtemplates. When adding the row, I need to show/hide a column based on a bool flag. This code `$('#tableid td:nth-child(3)').hide();` gets the job is done, but I can see the column appear for a split second (and the table appears wonky) before it disappears. How do I make it faster?

I tried using `$('#tableid td:eq(2)').hide();`, but it only hides the first row's column. Is there a way I can speed it up so the hide/show is smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the cells of the column that you need to toggle a specific class...

```
<table id="tableid">
    <tr>
       <td>...</td> <td>...</td> <td class="toggle">...</td> <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>...</td> <td>...</td> <td class="toggle">...</td> <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>...</td> <td>...</td> <td class="toggle">...</td> <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...then take care of hiding it in your CSS...

```css
#tableid.hide_col td.toggle {
    display:none;
}
```

So now the only JavaScript needed would be to add the class to the table.

```
$('#tableid').addClass('hide_col')
```

This lets the browser take care of hiding/showing with minimal JavaScript overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `td` already has a class. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @enigma: No, just give it another class. You can have multiple classes separated by a space character. `<td class="current_cls toggle">...</td>` You just want to make sure that the targeted column has some unique class that the other cells don't have.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it but it hides only the first row's (header) column.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to add the class in the jtemplate file for the dynamic row. It's all good now and much faster! Thank you for the example!!